# Append CSV or Text File in Swift 2

Tags: ios, file, csv, swift2, append

I am new to Swift and have spent days searching stackoverflow and on google to find an working example to append data in a csv/text file. There are couple of example/QA but I wasn't able to find the exact solution. Initially the problem was system failed to locate the local file in iPhone. Then I found error in creating the file path and appending value in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file name:

```
let fileName = "file"
```

Find the URL of the document directory:

```
let DocumentDirURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
```

Append the file name and extension to create the absolute file path:

```
let fileURL = DocumentDirURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName).URLByAppendingPathExtension("csv")
```

Use NSFileHandle to open the file:

```
let file: NSFileHandle? = NSFileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath: fileURL.path!)
```

Write data at the end of the file:

```
if file == nil {
        NSLog("File open failed")
    } else {
        // assuming data contains contents to be written
        let fileData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        // seek to end of the file to append at the end of the file.
        file?.seekToEndOfFile()
        file?.writeData(fileData!)
        file?.closeFile()
    }
```